# Force simplify to only use certain rules

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have an expression involving lots of trigonometric functions which I wish to simplify.  Unfortunately, `simplify()` and `trigsimp()` takes forever to complete which I suspect is because `simplify` is trying to use dozens of rules to try to simplify.

Suppose I already know before hand that I only want to simplify based on the identity
`sin(a)**2 + cos(a)**2 = 1` (note `a` may be a huge expression), is there some way to tell `simplify` to only use this rule, so that it might work faster in simplifying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `fu.py` routines for very targeted trigonometric transformations.